# Перемещение камеры вслед за персонажем

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы камера не флипалась (поворачивалась) вместе с персонажем, но перемещалась за с ним?

Comment: А как вы сейчас двигаете камеру?

Comment: Вы когда юнити запускаете там есть вкладка с примерами готовых игр, там все есть из базового функционала игры

Comment: Написать скрипт слежки для камеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самое простое это поместить камеру в другой пустой объект немного изменить координату Z. Этот объект, с камерой внутри, уже будет следовать за персонажем. Смысл в том, что этот объект (я бы назвал CameraRig) , будет выполнять функцию крана камеры, камера будет в нем и при его поворотах будет смотреть его центр.

в скрипте этой камеры нужна ссылка на твоего персонажа, чтобы сделать плавное следование за ним.

```
public class CameraRig : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField] private Transform character;
    [SerializedField] private float smoothTime = 1.5; //примерно

    private Vector3 vel;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, character.position, ref vel, smoothTime); //плавно перемещает камеру в точку координату персонажа
        transform.forward = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.forward, character.forward, ref vel, smoothTime); //плавно перемещает forward (поворачивает) cameraRig чтобы смотреть в то же место, куда и персонаж.

        //можно еще иметь ссылку на саму камеру и сделать что-то типа
        cam.transform.LookAt(character.position); // смотрит на персонажа

        // ну также можно сюда засунуть облет препятствий, например, если сзади стена, то подлетаешь камерой (делаешь Z меньше) к персонажу
    }
}
```

Это просто начало. То, что я здесь описал довольно примитивно. Дальше уже зависит от того, что ты хочешь. Кстати, можно вместо SmoothDamp использовать Lerp или MoveToward .. зависит от того, какой поведение тебе нужно. Можно даже использовать пакет Unity Cinemachine , если тебе нужно что-то из коробки

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как повернуть игрока в скрипте запоминай поворот камеры.

```
    private Vector3 tempCamRot = Camera.main.gameObject.eulerAngles;
```

А после поворота игрока возвращай камере поворот.

```
    Camera.main.gameObject.eulerAngles = tempCamRot;
```